# Saving data with uniq fields

Tags: hibernate

**Problem :** for simple example we have next table :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "books")
 public class Book {
     // other columns
     private Set<Genre> genres = new LinkedHashSet<>();

     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinTable(name = "book_genre", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="book_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="genre_id")})
     @OrderBy("name ASC")    
     public Set<Genre> getGenres() {
             return genres;
     }
 }
```

**Genre** table(entity) has unique column **name**, and this column already contains row with name *Example genre*, now if i'll try to save new **book** entity with same genre name :

```
  Set<Genre> newBookGenres = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  Genre newBookGenre = new Genre("Example genre"); //new genre with name [Example genre]
  newBookGenres.add(newBookGenre);
  Book book = new Book(newBookGenres);
  session.save(book);
```

it will not save that book and throw exception for unique column (*Example genre* already exists in genre name).

**Question :** how can i save entities like that? I think, before saving the book, i could search **genre** table for that book genre names and if there are (in database) genre with the same name, then just replace book genre object with database genre object. But im not sure if it will work and  believe that there is much simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

You variant ,is good , working variant.It's good practices .You can add some validation in java side , for validate that object already exists , and not call dao method for saving if validation is failing. In this case you don't need to try save entity and catching exception. You save time with validation , as save() method might be not so simple as you showed.

Also you can wrap dao method save() it catch block and work with exception , but it's bad practices as you should work with runtime exception instead of handling it with validation in advance.

As your entity(copy) might be modifyed by another user or users during your saving it might bring db constains problem even if your validation was ok. In this case use version for optimistic lock.

Also, do all checks in advance if you can.